# Java Complex Class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, unit-testing

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first complex number: ");
        double c1Real = input.nextDouble();
        double c1Imag = input.nextDouble();
        Complex c1 = new Complex(c1Real, c1Imag);

        System.out.print("Enter the second complex number: ");
        double c2Real = input.nextDouble();
        double c2Imag = input.nextDouble();
        Complex c2 = new Complex(c2Real, c2Imag);

        System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " + " + "(" + c2 + ")" + " = " + c1.add(c2));
        System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " - " + "(" + c2 + ")" + " = " + c1.subtract(c2));
        System.out.println("(" + c1 + ")" + " * " + "(" + c2 + ")" + " = " + c1.multiply(c2));
    }

    public Complex add(Complex c2) {
        double totalRealPart = this.real + c2.getReal();
        double totalImagPart = this.imag + c2.getImag();
        return new Complex(totalRealPart, totalImagPart);
    }

    public Complex subtract(Complex c2){
        double totalRealPart = this.real - c2.getReal();
        double totalImagPart = this.imag - c2.getImag();
        return new Complex(totalRealPart, totalImagPart);
    }

    public Complex multiply (Complex c2){
        double totalRealPart = this.real * c2.getReal();
        double totalImagPart = this.imag * c2.getImag();
        return new Complex(totalRealPart, totalImagPart);

}
```

I seem to keep having the same repeated issue for the most part, but I'm unable to figure out what.  Suggestions?

Description  Resource   Path    Location    Type

//not sure what this is//
Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.     JUnit       Build path  JRE System Library Problem
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.   try     Build path  JRE System Library Problem

//my errors//
Scanner cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 4  Java Problem

line 8  Java Problem
Scanner cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 4  Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 13 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 8  Java Problem
Syntax error on token "/", delete this token    TestAssignment7.java    /_pasted_code_/sources  line 1  Java Problem
Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.     Product     Build path  JRE System Library Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    TestAssignment7.java    /_pasted_code_/sources  line 1  Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 37 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 20 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 13 Java Problem
real cannot be resolved or is not a field   Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 21 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 20 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 23 Java Problem
imag cannot be resolved or is not a field   Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 22 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 26 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 26 Java Problem
imag cannot be resolved or is not a field   Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 28 Java Problem
real cannot be resolved or is not a field   Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 27 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 32 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 29 Java Problem
real cannot be resolved or is not a field   Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 33 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 32 Java Problem
Complex cannot be resolved to a type    Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources

line 35 Java Problem
imag cannot be resolved or is not a field   Test.java   /_pasted_code_/sources  line 34 Java Problem

Comment: Do you have a `Complex` type? The `Scanner` error can be fixed by adding an `import java.util.Scanner;` at the top of your code (but after the `package`, if there is one).

Comment: This is nonsense code. The functions `add`, `subtract`, etc. were clearly meant to be inside a class called `Complex` because they refer to `this.real` and `this.imag`, but you copy-pasted them into a class called `Test` that doesn't have these fields. *Don't do that.*

Answer (score 0):

For the JRE System Library Problem, you should:

-Right click on your project.

-Then select Properties. Select "Java build path".

-Then from "libraries" tab, remove "JRE System Library". Then at the same window, click "Add library",and add "JRE System Library", click Next, and tick "Workspace default JRE", and then click Ok.

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm late on this but there's a mistake about multiplication;
the formula is:

```
double totalRealPart = this.real * c2.getReal() - this.imag * c2.getImag();
double totalImagPart = this.real * c2.getImag() + this.imag * c2.getReal();
```

hope it helps!